# Sort list of coordinates

Tags: geometry, coordinates

I have the following problem:
I have a list of all the x, y coordinates of a polygon's points.
I now need to sort them in such a way that I obtain the points in a
clockwise order.

Currently I have the 6 coordinates to draw a polygon but its not in order.

Does anyone know how to accomplish that?

> ```
> Input coordinates :
>
> Coordinate: 506.6609866568262, 673.970398950142
>
> Coordinate: 505.34898334317376, 682.8179210498581
>
> Coordinate: 502.0723751660178, 680.523615304454
>
> Coordinate: 534.3026433431738, 682.736131049858
>
> Coordinate: 535.6146466568263, 673.8886089501419
>
> Coordinate: 538.8912548339822, 676.1829146955461
>
> Output coordinates :
>
> Coordinate: 506.6609866568262, 673.970398950142
>
> Coordinate: 502.0723751660178, 680.523615304454
>
> Coordinate: 505.34898334317376, 682.8179210498581
>
> Coordinate: 534.3026433431738, 682.736131049858
>
> Coordinate: 538.8912548339822, 676.1829146955461
>
> Coordinate: 535.6146466568263, 673.8886089501419
> ```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What language? What have you tried so far? Can you give an example input/output format?

Comment: Thanx for quick response. I am doing this program in Java. I tried to check each coordinate by comparison x as well as y. But I failed to compute a correct order.

Comment: What do you know of the output polygon? Do you have a set of edges? Or you need to generate a simple polygon from those points? If it is the second, then take an extremal point, maybe the one left most, i.e. your first point, then sort the points radially around it, and that will give you the points of a simple polygon in clockwise order or counter clockwise depending in how you define greater than. Take a look at [Graham's scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan), it sort the points clockwise around the lowest point at its first step.

Comment: why is this question voted down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use polar coordinates:

1. find an internal point to the polygon as a reference, say (c,d);
2. use `atan2(x-c, y-d)` for each vertex (x,y) of the polygon to get the polar angles from that internal point; then
3. sort by the angles you get.

If the polygon is convex, averaging the max and min values of x and likewise for y should get you an internal point. Otherwise, you have more work to do.

Comment: internal point to the polygon means center point of the polygon?

Comment: Not necessarily the exact middle; any point that is inside the polygon will do. Think about a 'clock hand' extending from the reference point - you want it to touch the vertices in the required order as it sweeps around. If the point was outside the polygon, it can hit vertices in some other order.

Comment: If two angles are same then how to handle this case?

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty If two angles are the same relative to an internal point, and you have at least 3 points, then you don't have a convex polygon.